# PHP display image according to date

Tags: php, image, date, echo

I'm working on a small script to display certain images according to date.
This is what I have to far, and I have to say that I really thought it would work:

```
<?php
$events = array(
 array(
  'image' => 'img/summer.png',
  'start' => '01-05-2017',
  'end' => '01-09-2017'
 ),
 array(
  'image' => 'img/christmas.png',
 'start' => '01-12-2017',
 'end' => '31-12-2017'
 )
);

foreach($events as $event) {
 if(date('d-m-Y') >= $event['start'] && date('d-m-Y') <= $event['end']) {
  echo "<img src='".$event['image']."'>";
 }
}
?>
```

I want to add as many arrays I want, in case I need to display more images at certain dates. I thought this should work, but it just returns a blank page. Any ideas on why it won't work?

Comment: Have you checked the source code of your page? Are you sure the images aren't there and you simply have broken links?

Comment: Should work just fine: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc9a85d34fec9edf6eebdb4bac01becbedfb0264 as @JulienLachal said, probably just a broken link

Comment: its not working properly try using strtotime with dates for comparing

Comment: _“Any ideas on why it won't work?”_ – because you have not thought about how string comparison actually works - character-by-character, starting from the left.

Comment: Didn't think of that, @anju. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to convert your dates in to `strtotime` while comparing dates so you get accepted result. otherwise  wrong comparison will done

```
$events = array(
 array(
  'image' => 'img/summer.png',
  'start' => '01-05-2017',
  'end' => '01-09-2017'
 ),
 array(
  'image' => 'img/christmas.png',
 'start' => '01-12-2017',
 'end' => '31-12-2017'
 )
);
$date_to_compare=strtotime(date('d-m-Y'));
foreach($events as $event) {
 if($date_to_compare >= strtotime($event['start']) && $date_to_compare <= strtotime($event['end'])) {
  echo "<img src='".$event['image']."'>";
 }
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this piece of code! I was searching for something similar. Is it also possible to combine the code with and without checking the year? 
For example (in your example) you also make it check on year. But I want it also check a date without a year (Christmas, birthdays and such are always on the same date). Special things, for example, World / European soccer championships are on specific dates. I hope you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes its possible also. But you need to provide code for further solution

Comment: I didn't make any changes to the code you posted here, so it's the same as above. Well actually I just did fool around with your code. If I remove Y from it, it will work, however it doesn't check the year anymore for other (non-standard) dates. I want them to be combined, so it looks up dates with and without a year.